# vue js input file laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

как передать изображение в контроллер, в консоле выдает название файла, но в контроллере я принимаю null

```
<input type="file" name="image" @change="loadBanner">

import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
        el: '#add_catalog_link',
        data: function(){
            return {
                max: 160,
                paysystems: [],
                showpay: false,
                activec: 0,
                sUsd: '',
                form: {
                    url: '',
                    urlbanner: '',
                    image: '',
                    typebanner: 1,
                    politic: false,
                    days: 5,
                    cost: 0
                }
            }
        },
        computed: {
            costOrder: function() {
                var result = 0,
                    countDays = this.form.days;
                if(this.form.typebanner === 1) result = countDays * 29; else result = countDays * 19;
                return result
            },
            usd(){
                return this.sUsd
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getPaySystems()
            this.paySystemCost()
            this.getUsd()
        },
        methods: {
            loadBanner(event) {
                this.image = event.target.files[0].name;
                console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
                console.log(this.image);
            },
            saveLinkToCatalog(pay_id){

                axios.post('/banners/add-user',{pid:pay_id,url:this.form.url,urlbanner:this.form.urlbanner,typebanner:this.form.typebanner,days:this.form.days,cost:this.costOrder,image:this.form.image})
                    .then((response) => {
                        if (response.data.error === 0){
                            toast.fire({
                                type: 'success',
                                title: response.data.message
                            })
                        }else{
                            toast.fire({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: response.data.message
                            })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {});

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут вы записываете имя файла, просто в `this.image`, а в `axios` передаете `image:this.form.image`

```
loadBanner(event) {
                this.image = event.target.files[0].name;
                console.log(event.target.files[0].name);
                console.log(this.image);
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

я понял свою ошибку, сделал событие на `submit`

- вот такой маневр

  ```
              const config = { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
              const formData = new FormData()
              formData.append('pid', pay_id);
              formData.append('url', this.form.url);
              formData.append('urlbanner', this.form.urlbanner);
              formData.append('typebanner', this.form.typebanner);
              formData.append('days', this.form.days);
              formData.append('image', this.form.image);
              formData.append('cost', this.costOrder);

              axios.post('/banners/add-user',formData,config)
                  .then((response) => {
                      if (response.data.error === 0){
                          toast.fire({
                              type: 'success',
                              title: response.data.message
                          })
                      }else{
                          toast.fire({
                              type: 'error',
                              title: response.data.message
                          })
                      }
                  })
                  .catch(error => {});
  ```